# Cannot find which application uses port with netstat

Tags: windows-vista

```
netstat -o -n -a | findstr 0.0:80
```

gives me a PID of 4 but in my vista task manager I can't see any process with such PID.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the process is running as a different user, click **show processes from all users**:

[image]

You can also use `netstat -b` which will show you an executable name as well as a PID:

```
Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
TCP    john:1038              localhost:1039         ESTABLISHED     1400
[firefox.exe]
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have clicked "Show processes from all users" in the bottom left hand corner.

Failing this, take a look at Microsoft / Sysinternals [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which is basically an enhanced free task manager.